# MTOUCH: Error MT0024: Could not find required file iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk"/SDKSettings.plist

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode7, xamarin-studio

I have upgraded my xamarin for IOS9 with  xcode7. After updating I am getting lots of issues. Please check following error :

> MTOUCH: Error MT0024: Could not find required file
>   '"/Applications/Xcode7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk"/SDKSettings.plist'.
>   (MT0024)

Your Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Weird thing is that, I checked the path given for plist file, it's there but still the issue.

Stuck since 2 days :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue. In my case, I followed below steps and it worked for me .

1) Remove the spacing between Xcode Name. In my case it was Xcode 7 so renamed this with Xcode7.

2) add mtouch argument -v -v -v -v.

Clean and build the solution.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, Let me try

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where the answer above didn't work.
The problem is that Visual Code is looking for an iOS version that no longer exists after an update. For example: I updated XCode to 14.5 from 14.4 and it was searching for 14.4

This issue probably gets solved automatically but without needing to restart I just symlinked the current version to the missing 14.4 path:

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
$ sudo ln -s iPhoneSimulator.sdk  iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was occured due to update of Xcode latest version (same as Jorden mentioned) and but I was able to solve it by changing the below setting on the Xamarin project.
Change the settings to "Don't Link".

[image]